# Why is HashTable Delete O(1)?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I understand why a HashTable Add is O(1) (however please correct me if I'm wrong): The item being added is always allocated to the first available spot in the backing array.

I understand why a Lookup is O(n) (again, please correct me if I'm wrong): You need to walk through the backing array to find the value/key requested, and the running time of this operation will be directly proportional to the size of the collection.

However, why, then, is a Delete [constant?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) Seems to me the same principals involved in an Add/Lookup are required.

**EDIT**

The MSDN article refers to a scenario where the item requested to be deleted isn't found. It mentions this as being an O(1) operation.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean "Lookup is O(n)" - constant time for search is may benefit of Hash tables...

Comment: Worst case is O(n): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: I see what you mean. Note that you are posting average ([amortizided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) ) time for some of operations (Add/Delete) and worst for others (Lookup)... This makes it hard to correctly answer your question.

Comment: Please consider to edit your post to clearly specify if you are mentioning average or worst cases for each method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worst cases for Insert and Delete are supposed to be `O(n)`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table.

When we Insert, we have to check if the value is in the table or not, hence `O(n)` in the worst case.

Just imagine a pathological case when all hash values are the same.

Maybe MSDN refers to average complexity.

Comment: They are referring to a scenario where they key isn't found... however this would mean that the entire array has been searched, which would be an O(n) operation, wouldn't it?

Comment: @NealR If the key is not found, then there are no hash collisions, so I'd expect `O(1)`. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No, you understand the question. Why would this be O(1) if the entire collection was iterated over, though?

Comment: +1. @NealR - worst case for each Add/Lookup/Delete is O(n), average for each Add/Lookup/Delete is O(1). Worst case can be easily demonstrated when Hash function is constant (like `return 42;`).

Comment: @NealR Why the entire collection will be iterated over if key is not found? The idea is that we get hash function in `O(1)`, and if the value does not exist in the table, we know everything. The problem appears if the value does exist in the table, and is the same for different objects. In that case we have to check objects one by one.

Answer (score 1):

O(1) is the best case, and probably the average case if you appropriately size the table.  Worst case deletion for a HashTable is O(n).